# css/js to wobble (rotate) image VS photoshop animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, rotation, photoshop

I'm planning to use photoshop to make an animated image - a 3D object that spins like a top.

A webpage I'm making will show several identical images which spin exactly the same way.

Also, they all need to "wobble" back and forth (rotate a few degrees CW/CCW), but each at different speeds...

My question is, should I make 1 spinning-top image and then use css/js to handle the wobbling, using that same file for the image source? Or should I make several images in photoshop each with their unique wobble built into the animation?

Are there any pros/cons I should consider for either way?

Comment: What kind of animation are you talking about exactly? Animated GIF? CSS transitions/animations? Scripted SVG? JavaScript "flipbook" style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What audience will your site be serving? If it's large scale site, you should make your decision based on which option uses the least bandwidth.

If you're catering to a small audience, I would use whatever effect looks best.

As for the animation, I would control the wobble using javascript. It's better because you'll have something you can modifying later vs a static animation which you might have to remake.